# Conservation equations in a vortex

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, vortex

I have compared several models of vortex with experimental measurements considering only azimuthal velocity. So now, I would like to check if the conservation equations are satisfied at every point. How can I apply standard conservation equations in order to verify that?

Comment: Conservation of what? What do you mean by "apply"? Do you mean perform an experiment or give a theoretical explanation?

Comment: energy conservation for example. Rather to give a theorical explanation

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned there are several models to represent a vortex.

And conservation equations are valid at every single point of fluid flow.

My two suggestions  are,

1. Don't apply any conservation equation at the critical point if you assume vortex with singular points (ex. free vortex).
2. use cylindrical coordinate equation for 2D. It will be more convenient to get rid of few terms in the equations.

There are plenty of books to refer about the vortex especially vortex dynamics by P.G. Saffman https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511624063